# Running Grunt commands Windows 8

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, npm

I am trying to install Grunt using

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

But am getting an error I do not know how to interpret, I am new to Grunt and web dev. I am certain I have a valid installation of npm and node.js.
If anyone could explain what the following npm-debug file means and/or what I should do to get a valid grunt installation, that would be extremely helpful.

I am installing Grunt because it is used to build Bootstrap.
Sorry to dump a big error log, I am not sure how much of it is meaningful.

```
11 verbose addNamed [ 'grunt-cli', '' ]
12 verbose addNamed [ null, '*' ]
13 silly lockFile d63f3d0b-grunt-cli grunt-cli@
14 verbose lock grunt-cli@ C:\Users\Kelsey\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\d63f3d0b-grunt-cli.lock
15 silly addNameRange { name: 'grunt-cli', range: '*', hasData: false }
16 verbose url raw grunt-cli
17 verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './grunt-cli' ]
18 verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
19 info trying registry request attempt 1 at 10:24:14
20 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
21 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo EAGAIN
22 info trying registry request attempt 2 at 10:24:24
23 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
24 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo EAGAIN
25 info trying registry request attempt 3 at 10:25:24
26 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
27 silly lockFile d63f3d0b-grunt-cli grunt-cli@
28 silly lockFile d63f3d0b-grunt-cli grunt-cli@
29 error Error: getaddrinfo EAGAIN
29 error     at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
29 error     at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
30 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
30 error including the npm and node versions, at:
30 error     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
31 error System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
32 error command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
33 error cwd c:\Users\Kelsey\Documents
34 error node -v v0.10.29
35 error npm -v 1.4.14
36 error syscall getaddrinfo
37 error code EAGAIN
38 error errno EAGAIN
39 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the cmd/command shell is attempting to run grunt commands with insufficient permissions.

Start the cmd/command shell as administrator, then the problem should be resolved.